# Wrapping ajax elements to HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

So I have already fetched data from our mongodb database using Ajax. I can retrieve the data and from database store it inside javascript variables successfully.

Firstly, What I want is to put the data back on the HTML page like inside the  blocks. Should it be done using Jquery  and put in CSS tags? I have the data stored in global variables inside javascript. How could this be done?

Second, after we have loads of data with text elements and the strings vary in length. So how do I make sure that whatever text I put on the HTML page is properly aligned to our canvas width and height everytime. It should not exceed the canvas width. How can this be achieved?

---

So this is my css element

```
#disp_prob_title{
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            top: 450px;
            left: 240px;
            height: 150px;
            width: 350px;
        }
```

And this is the Javascript function where I want to append it

```
setQuestion : function(titleString, bodyString, hintString){
               $("#disp_prob_title").append(this.qsName);
        },
```

this.qsName is a global variable in my js file and it retrieve a string correctly on logs. However I do not see any text on my html page. Also how do I change the font size and color inside the css element?

Thanks!

Comment: What does _and put in CSS tags_ mean? Do you want to put the data into a stylesheet or what?

Comment: yea. Sorry for the confusion. I am still new to the terminologies of web programming :) 
Yes I want to display the data on my html page. Its like whenever an event gets triggered, the new data is retrieved from the database and I want to show the new data on the html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "put in CSS tags". You could do something like give the block of html you wish to have your content in an id like "content" then use jQuery add, append,  appendTo, etc. method to append the content to the content block.

Html block would look like:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Then once you fetch the data:

```
$("#content").append("<div>some data here</div>");
```

As far as forcing the content to remain the right size etc. you'll have to add some styling to the content block or the content you append to that block.

Your question was a little vague so hopefully this helps?

Comment: Yes I will try that. And sorry for not being clear enough. In simple terms I just want to display the data I get from my database to my main HTML page. Every time a specific event gets triggered a new piece of data is retrieved from the database. So in short I want to show this updated data on my html page whenever my events get triggered

Comment: Can you throw an alert/console.log in that function above? Or add a breakpoint in your source at that point. Is it even hitting that function?

Comment: Yup I put an alert box inside the function and it shows up. So I am pretty sure it reached the function. Also I tried putting it in my main draw function but still nothing shows up.

Comment: Is there a value when you do alert(this.qsName); or console.log(this.qsName); ?

Answer (score 0):

It works now, I had to change the styling to

```
#disp_prob_title{
            position: absolute;
            width: 30%;
            top: 250px;
            left: 150px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

Thank you for your help!